# Is it possible to set a custom type in jOOQ not only based on the column name or data type, but on the table name?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have one project with IDs in the database named like `FOO_ID` (for the table `FOO`). I find it convenient to define a small class in Java called `FooId` wrapping the actual value, and map the `FOO_ID` column's type to `FooId` in Java. This allows for better type checking, as I can't accidentally write a "foo id" into a "bar id" column without the compiler giving me an error.

On a new project, all the ID columns are simply called `ID` in every table. I can't change the database schema, that's out of my hands alas. I would love for `<forcedType>` to be able to match "column named 'ID' in table named 'FOO'" but right now I can't see how to do that, I don't think it's possible.

Is it possible to constrain `<forcedType>` based on the table name in addition to the column name? If so, what's the syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Existing feature request

This idea has been discussed on the [jOOQ mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/53RZqoewa3g/KB9bZDKDBAAJ) a couple of times and there's also a pending feature request that will add support for a special generated key type: [#6124](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6124).

In addition to what you suggested, foreign key types should match their referenced primary key types. The challenge with these types is to make it work for all edge cases including:

- Composite keys
- Unique keys (which can also be referenced by foreign keys in many databases)
- Columns participating in several unique keys / foreign keys

While this is certainly an interesting feature, it is not yet available in jOOQ 3.9.

#### Workaround

You can work around this limitation yourself by:

- Extending the `JavaGenerator` in order to generate your own type per primary key / foreign key
- Using `<forcedType/>` to replace all single-column key types by your own generated types

This is best done by using the programmatic code generation configuration - otherwise you'd be typing quite a bit of XML (of course, you could also use XSLT to generate the config).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The feature request looks great indeed. I am currently using `<forcedType>` for those columns which have names like `foo_id`. But some tables simply have a primary key called e.g. `id`. Multiple tables have columns called `id` so I cannot map to a special type based on the column name alone. Is it possible to persuade `<forcedType>` to take into account not only the column name, but also the table name?

Comment: @AdrianSmith: Yeah, `<forcedType><expression>` matches both (fully) qualified and unqualified column names. Just remember that fully qualified means `schema.table.column`. If you don't care about the schema, use something like: `.*?\.my_table\.id`